# VB code of Excel 2013 is not responsive

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a formulation to form the name of equipment. First part (Bname = "H" Or Bname = "S") is working well. The second part (ElseIf Bname = "04" Or Bname = 4 Or Bname = "03" Or Bname = "02" Or Bname = "01" Or Bname = "00" Or Bname = "B" Or Bname = "B1") is not responsive.

I'm pretty sure that this code was working in the earlier version 2010. Can anyone advice what's went wrong with code.

Input:

> Location Equip Sensor
>
> H-00-15-0-27 FCU-GF-03 DISCHARGE TEMP,

Output:

> Sensor Name Appearing
>
> FCUGF03_H_00_15.0_27_DsTmp

```
Function Name_Alpha(Equipment_Tag As String, Sensor_Tag As String, Location_Tag As String) As String

Dim Bname As String
Dim Bname2 As String
Dim Bname3 As String
Dim Bname4 As String
Dim Bname5 As String

Dim EquipTag As Variant
Dim EquipTag2 As String
Dim EquipTag3 As String
Dim SensorTag As String

Bname = Split(Location_Tag, "-")(0)
Bname2 = Split(Trim(Split(Location_Tag, "-")(1)), "-")(0)
Bname3 = Split(Trim(Split(Location_Tag, "-")(2)), "-")(0)
Bname4 = Split(Trim(Split(Location_Tag, "-")(3)), "-")(0)
Bname5 = Split(Trim(Split(Location_Tag, "-")(4)), "-")(0)

EquipTag = Split(Equipment_Tag, "-")(0)
EquipTag2 = Split(Trim(Split(Equipment_Tag, "-")(1)), "-")(0)
EquipTag3 = Split(Trim(Split(Equipment_Tag, "-")(2)), "-")(0)

SensorTag = Split(Sensor_Tag, " ")(0)

If Bname = "H" Or Bname = "S" Then
    If EquipTag = "FCU" Or EquipTag = "WMU" Then
        If SensorTag = "TEMPERATURE" Then
            Name_Alpha = EquipTag & EquipTag2 & EquipTag3 & "_" & Bname & "_" & Bname2 & "_" & Bname3 & "." & Bname4 & "_" & Bname5 & "_ZnTmp"
        ElseIf SensorTag = "DISCHARGE" Then
            Name_Alpha = EquipTag & EquipTag2 & EquipTag3 & "_" & Bname & "_" & Bname2 & "_" & Bname3 & "." & Bname4 & "_" & Bname5 & "_DsTmp"
        End If
    End If

    ElseIf Bname = "04" Or Bname = 4 Or Bname = "03" Or Bname = "02" Or Bname = "01" Or Bname = "00" Or Bname = "B" Or Bname = "B1" Then
        If EquipTag = "FCU" Or EquipTag = "WMU" Then
            If SensorTag = "TEMPERATURE" Then
            Name_Alpha = EquipTag & EquipTag2 & EquipTag3 & "_" & Bname & "_" & Bname2 & "_" & Bname3 & "." & Bname4 & "_ZnTmp"
            ElseIf SensorTag = "DISCHARGE" Then
                Name_Alpha = EquipTag & EquipTag2 & EquipTag3 & "_" & Bname & "_" & Bname2 & "_" & Bname3 & "." & Bname4 & "_DsTmp"
            End If
        End If
    

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Can you show sample input and expected output?

Comment: Should this '4' be in quotes: Bname = 4 -> Bname = "4"

Comment: Hi, Thanks alot for your respond. Here is the input and expected output:

Comment: The code works for me, and doesn't go anywhere near the `ElseIf` (because `BName` is "H").

Answer (score 1):

With the following changes, this works correctly using your test data:

Change

```
Dim EquipTag As Variant
```

To

```
Dim EquipTag As String
```

And change

```
ElseIf Bname = "04" Or Bname = 4 Or Bname = "03" Or Bname = "02" Or Bname = "01" Or Bname = "00" Or Bname = "B" Or Bname = "B1" Then
```

to

```
ElseIf Bname = "04" Or Bname = "4" Or Bname = "03" Or Bname = "02" Or Bname = "01" Or Bname = "00" Or Bname = "B" Or Bname = "B1" Then
```